# Can not import libraries in different Python version

Tags: python, import, version, libraries

I installed Python 3.5.2 64 bit version on my Windows. I had already Python 3.6.4 32-bit version. I needed 64 bit one because I want to use Tensorflow which requires 64-bit version.

However, after installation I can not import libraries on Python 3.5.2. When I try pip3 install command it says  "requirement already satisfied" but when it comes to importing it says "no module named".

I want to import all necessary libraries on 3.5.2 just like my original 3.6.4 version but I can not do it. 
Any support would be really appreciated. Here is an image showing the error.

No module named "numpy" :

[image: No module named "numpy"]

Comment: try deleting the old version of python

Comment: check which version of pip you have installed and pointing for pip3
ls -l `which pip3`

Comment: I don't want to delete the old one since it has many libraries already, so it will be my last choice if I could not find any other solution. I guess "which pip3" command is not working on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

When you type `pip3 install ...`, it most likely refers to the `pip` of your `3.6` installation. When you installed the `3.5` version, you most likely got a `pip3.5` executable (I don't know the exact name in Windows, maybe `pip35`), you should use this one for installing packages for your `Python 3.5`.

On Linux, that's what happens anyways.

Comment: It is indeed pip of 3.6. I have pip3.5 executable but when I try to enter "pip3.5 install numpy" for example it says " Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'  " .  I need another way to make use of  pip3.5 I guess. Somehow it is always directing python 3.6 when I use pip3.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, specifying the Python version before -m pip install package_name is a solution for this problem.

For example:

python3.5 -m pip install numpy

I just need not to use pip3 since it somehow belongs to the Python 3.6.4 ( older one ). With that I can import numpy without a problem.

Very appreciated for your helps.